# Question on Sparse Cyclic Diagonal Matrices: How to Prove Regularity of Eigenvector Structures Numerically?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a $N \times N$ diagonal matrix *A* with an infinite cycle with a period of 3, and an infinite cyclic matrix *B*, as follows. Assume $\Phi$ is a matrix of eigenvectors of $A^{-1}B$, where $\Phi^{T}A\Phi=I$, *I* is the $N \times N$ identity matrix.

Currently, a $N \times N$ diagonal matrix *C* has been constructed as follows, the elements of *A* is redistributed while keeping the sum of the element same. How can I get the general rule of the diagnonal element of matrix $\Phi^{T}C\Phi$?

Through numerical calculations, I have found that when *N* is is sufficiently large, the first diagonal element of $\Phi^{T}C\Phi$ is  1. How can this be proven?

*A*=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & & & \\
0 & a_2 & 0 & \cdots & & & \\
0 & 0 & a_3 & \cdots & & & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & & & \\
& & & & a_1 & 0 & 0 \\
& & & & 0 & a_2 & 0 \\
& & & & 0 & 0 & a_3 \\
& & & & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}

*B*=\begin{bmatrix}
2b & -b & 0 & \cdots & & & \\
-b & 2b & -b & \cdots & & & \\
0 & -b & 2b & -b & \cdots & & \\
\vdots & \vdots & -b & 2b & -b & \cdots & \\
& & \vdots & -b & 2b & -b & 0 \\
& & & \vdots & -b & 2b & -b \\
& & & & 0 & -b & 2b & \ddots \\
& & & & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}

*C*=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & & & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & & & \\
0 & 0 & a_1+a_2+a_3 & \cdots & & & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & & & \\
& & & & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& & & & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
& & & & 0 & 0 & a_1+a_2+a_3 \\
& & & & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed the expression of the question. I am trying to get the theoretical basis of the numerical results in my model.